# Odoo: How to link fields to each other?

Tags: python, many-to-many, one-to-many, odoo, many-to-one

I am trying to link fields from different classes in Odoo.
It should be something similar to foreign key.

This is my case:
There are 2 classes with their own tree views.

Class 1: opc_taginstellingen:

```
class opc_taginstellingen(models.Model):
    _name = 'opc_taginstellingen'

    Tagnaam = fields.Char(string="Tagnaam")
    Unit = fields.Char(string="Unit")
```

Class 2: opc_actuelewaardentags

```
class opc_actuelewaardentags(models.Model):
    _name = 'opc_actuelewaardentags'

    TagNaam = fields.Char(string="Tagnaam")
    TagWaarde = fields.Integer(string="Tagwaarde")
```

What I want to do now is:

In opc_actuelewaardentags, get Unit from opc_taginstellingen where TagNaam (opc_actuelewaardentags) == Tagnaam (opc_actuelewaardentags).

Then I want to be able to also show Unit in the tree view of opc_actuelewaardentags. But I guess that won't be a problem.

Also mind the difference Tag**n**aam and Tag**N**aam.

What i've tried so far:

I've been playing with relational fields, many2one's, one2many and many2many. Couldn't get it to work yet...

This is what I've put in class opc_actuelewaardentags, but didn't work:

```
Unit1 = fields.Many2one('opc_taginstellingen', string="Unit1")
Unit1 = fields.Related('Unit', type="Many2One", relation="opc_taginstellingen", string="Unit1")
Unit1 = fields.Char(related='opc_taginstellingen.Unit', store=True)
```

**Edit:** After BSL Technologies' comment, I've changed everything to lower case so that can't be the issue.

There are no errors. But the value for unit doesn't show in the tree view of opc_actuelewaardentags. The title does.

This is my code now:

```
class opc_taginstellingen(models.Model):
    _name = 'opc_taginstellingen'

    tagnaam = fields.Char(string="Tagnaam")
    unit = fields.Char(string="unit")

class opc_actuelewaardentags(models.Model):
    _name = 'opc_actuelewaardentags'

    tagnaam = fields.Char(string="Tagnaam")      
    opc_tag = fields.Many2one('opc_taginstellingen', string="unit")
    unit = fields.Char(related='opc_tag.unit',string="unit")
```

Is there anything else why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1):

This field needs to be to added to the opc_actuelewaardentags class.

```
opc_tag = fields.Many2one('opc_taginstellingen', string="Unit1")
unit = fields.Char(related='opc_tag.Unit',string="Unit")
```

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately, I just tried it and doesn't work either...
Didn't get any errors now, the field shows up in the tree view but doesn't show any values...

Comment: Could it be something with the uppercase U in field "Unit"?
I already learnt I shouldn't use case sensitive names but anyway...
Tried some things:
Unit = fields.Char(related='opc_tag."Unit"',string="Unit") ==> gave an error
Unit = fields.Char(related='opc_tag.\"Unit\"',string="Unit") ==> gave an error
Do you still have any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have any idea why escaping double quotes doesn't work?

Comment: I have updated my OP. I tried your code with everything lower case but it doesn't work. Did you test the code?